# Is it possible to publish messages using JMS API and consume them using MQTT?

Tags: hornetq, activemq-artemis

Given an `abcTopic` topic on an Artemis (previously HornetQ) MQ server, internally it will be represented by the `jms.topic.abcTopic` address.
Can I somehow subscribe an MQTT client to this topic ?
The problem I see is that when I'm subscribing to a topic, internally it becomes an address prefixed with **$sys.mqtt** (`org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil#MQTT_ADDRESS_PREFIX`) so that result in the impossibility to connect to `jms.topic.abcTopic`.